# please explain the below code

Tags: jquery, foreach

```
var anArray = ['one','two','three'];
$.each(anArray,function(n,value) {
//do something here
});
var anObject = {one:1, two:2, three:3};
$.each(anObject,function(name,value) {
//do something here
});
```

here we didnt declare n at anywhere in first function
and in next function what is meant by name here.. and value
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `$.each()`, `n` (the first parameter) is the index number of the current iteration of the Array (or key name for the Object), and `value` (the second parameter) is the value of the item at the current index.

They are passed as arguments to the function you passed to `$.each()`.

So given the Array, each iteration in the loop would look like this:

```
n == 0, value == 'one'
n == 1, value == 'two'
n == 2, value == 'three'
```

For the Object, it would be this:

```
name == 'one', value == 1
name == 'two', value == 2
name == 'three', value == 3
```

Simple way to test it would be to log the variables to the console.

In place of:

```
// do something here
```

have:

```
console.log( n, value );    // for the Array
console.log( name, value ); // for the Object
```

> "here we didnt declare n at anywhere..."

They actually are declared as Formal Parameters to the function. As such, they will be local variables to that particular function call.

Answer (score 1):

See Jquery Each function reference
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Its a callback function which will be called for each element of array and value will be passed as follows:

```
name  : Index in Array
value : Current Value of the element
```

`n` is same as `Name`, just the variable name is changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
```

Here, n is the index in array that is passed while the callback is working on each element of anArray (or name of each property of anObject). Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/